# Firebase not creating new node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one node name users which is populating fine, but I am trying to incorporate a new node events, which I am having trouble with. I have copied exactly what works in the users, but I am clearly doing something wrong. It never goes into the OnCompleteListener. Is there something I am missing?

R.string.dbnode_events ="events"

```
Events events = new Events();
            events.setEvent_key(mEventKey);
            events.setEvent_title("");
            events.setEvent_date("");
            events.setEvent_time("");
            events.setEvent_millis("");
            events.setEvent_desc("");
            events.setEvent_filter("");
            events.setGroup_number("");


            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child(getString(R.string.dbnode_events))
                    .child(mEventKey)
                    .setValue(events).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateEventActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            });
```

More Information/ Example: The top user one creates a node no problem but the events one has yet to create. I hope this might give some more insight.

```
 User user = new User();
                    user.setName(email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@")));
                    user.setPhone("1");
                    user.setProfile_image("");
                    user.setSecurity_level("1");
                    user.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    user.setEmail(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                    user.setStreet_address("");
                    user.setCity("");
                    user.setState("");
                    user.setZip("");
                    user.setMember_filter("Member");
                    user.setSmall_group_subscription1("");
                    user.setSmall_group_subscription2("");
                    user.setSmall_group_subscription3("");
                    user.setSmall_group_subscription4("");
                    user.setSmall_group_subscription5("");
                    user.setShow_phone("No");
                    user.setShow_email("Yes");
                    user.setShow_address("No");

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child(getString(R.string.dbnode_users))
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(user)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                redirectLoginScreen();
                            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                redirectLoginScreen();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Database Problem ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                            });
/////////////////////////
                    String mEventKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    Events events = new Events();
                    events.setEvent_key(mEventKey);
                    events.setEvent_title("");
                    events.setEvent_date("");
                    events.setEvent_time("");
                    events.setEvent_millis("");
                    events.setEvent_desc("");
                    events.setEvent_filter("");
                    events.setGroup_number("");


                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child(getString(R.string.dbnode_events))
                            .child(mEventKey)
                            .setValue(events)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i have done, probably it will help :D

When you add a class, you have to create a reference like this :

```
  private DatabaseReference Accounts;
```

And inside the onCreate :

```
Accounts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Accounts");
```

After that, set ur class. I do this for the user :

```
currentwithID = new Class_user(uID,uSer,matchFound);
```

And than set it on the node : 
uID is the token given by Google

```
Accounts.child(uID).setValue(currentwithID);
```

I have done the same things to every node of my database, and it perfectly works. 
Try to do that with this code, and tell me if it works :D